# Dropbox like login?

Tags: android, android-layout, responsive-design

So, I want to create a responsive **Login Screen** for my app, that would adjust itself with my choice when the android **softkeyboard** gets visible.

***My Research:***

**Note:** I know `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"` this already so please don't suggest this only.

I have gone through a number of famous android apps like **facebook** etc. just to confirm weather it is a limitation to adjust screen with choice when **softkeyboard** gets visible.

Then I get across with **Dropbox** android app on my **Samsung galaxy tab 2** which is a `xlarge` screen. Now, when I tried to enter the email the screen adjusted itself in a very smooth and responsive manner. Similarly when I tried to enter the password then again the same thing happened. But I couldn't find any other opensource project which confirms such *responsivity when softkeyboard appears.*

Below are the screens which explain what I want to achieve in a similar fashion:

Please excuse me for the large sizes of images as I want to make my point clear. :)

- Login screen without keyboard

[image: Login screen without keyboard]

- Login screen when email edittext is pressed

[image: Login screen when email edittext is pressed]

- Login screen when password edittext is pressed

[image: Login screen when password edittext is pressed]

Please note the responsiveness of screens. If you have the app installed. Also there is a size difference between password and email screens below.

Answer (score 5):

The effect you're trying to achieve can done by setting `android:scaleType="fitXY"` on an ImageView background.

Edit- also you might want to set in your manifest

```
<activity name=".YourActivity"
    android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible|adjustResize">
</activity>
```

Comment: but how could I use it when keyboard appears on screen?

Comment: But I have already set `stateHidden` as I only want the softkeyboard to appear when the activity created.

Comment: Ok, I am using your answer with `android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustResize"`.

Comment: This is not making a difference to my layout as the edittext is there in the bottom of the screen.

Comment: when I put focus on the `edittext` that is similar to the password screen above then the keyboard overlays 1/5th of editext and it looks less intuitive.

Comment: You could try applying some bottom padding to the element - just a thought.

Comment: Ok will give it a try also. Thanks for your effort +1

Comment: Did you try adjustPan? That will not resize the window but ensures the focused field is always visible above the keyboard by panning the window upwards.

Comment: @BrettDuncavage Yea I did try adjustpan and adjustResize but just work the same moreover I want to achieve the above thing even for some future releases.

Answer (score 1):

Right of the top I can think of using a LinearLayout with weights so that the widgets stretch appropriately. Use `WRAP_CONTENT` for the heights of all the text widgets, and fill the remaining width with the ImageButton by setting the `width = 0dp` and `layout_weight = 1`.

Comment: Can you help it with some opensource project?

Answer (score 1):

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustResize"
```

Here is complete design of login screen:

http://www.androidhive.info/2011/10/android-login-and-registration-screen-design/